# Find and sort same months name as single in Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am working with Microsoft excel 2010. I have different dates like column E1:E19 that are not in specific interval. I want help to find only starts month date and paste them into G column like shown into the figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of, is to say - both K_B and *Ibrahim Odeh* have valid and good attemps. I just want to add another option, because those options use additional rows or manual tools.

Here is the formula I came up with to solve this as shown in your screenshot - just one column, just the rows with the starting dates:

```
G1=SUBTOTAL(5,E$1:E$19)

G2=SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(E$1:E$19,MATCH(EOMONTH(G1,0),E$1:E$19,1),0,ROWS(E$1:E$19)-MATCH(EOMONTH(G1,0),E$1:E$19,1)))
```

It is possible to use this for the whole column, like this:

```
G1=SUBTOTAL(5,E:E)

G2=SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(E:E,MATCH(EOMONTH(G1,0),E:E,1),0,ROWS(E:E)-MATCH(EOMONTH(G1,0),E:E,1)))
```

And now, some explaining:

First, you need a starting point in *G1* - so we use `SUBTOTAL` to get the earliest date in column E, using `MIN` (which is 5).

Now we work from here, by offsetting the range which we use to calculate our `SUBTOTAL`, still using `MIN` (5), to get the beginning of each month.

The trick is `OFFSET`. The first parameter is out basic range, which we will offset, then we have to determine how many rows to offset, and to not get an error, we use `ROWS(basicRange)` - rowOffset to always stay in out range.

`MATCH` is used to determine the necessary offset, by looking for the row of the last listed date of the month from *G1*  using `EOMONTH`.

Hope this clears any question.

*Edit:*

Because I do have to translate this, here is the original:

```
=TEILERGEBNIS(5;E:E)

=TEILERGEBNIS(5;BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(E:E;VERGLEICH(MONATSENDE(G1;0);E:E;1);0;ZEILEN(E:E)-VERGLEICH(MONATSENDE(G1;0);E:E;1)))
```

Comment: in the G2 formula you now refer to EOMONTH(G2) that should be G1 in stead of G2. Nice method indeed, no additional columns required, very clean!

Answer (score 1):

as long as your dates columns is sorted as it looks in the example then do the following:

insert a row above row 1 (for use of the formula)
enter a formula in column A in all rows that your table has. The formula reads:

`=If(NOT(YEAR($E2)&MONTH($E2)=YEAR($E1)&MONTH($E1), MAX($F$1:$F1)+1, "")`

This will add increasing numbers from 1 to the number of months involved only next to the first date in your table for that month.

Then in your table in column G put:

`=VLOOKUP(ROW(), A:E, 5)`

you can drag this formula down as far as you want. The formula finds the first record in A:E that matches the row number in G (`ROW()` in G1 returns 1), Then `VLOOKUP()` will return the value in the 5th column in A:E (which is column E with the date).

The Formula in column A should be to the left of the dates for the `VLOOKUP()` formula to work.

Alternatively you can put it in a column to the right but then use another formula in stead of `VLOOKUP()` in column G:

`=SUMIF(F:F,ROW(),E:E)`

This sums all values in E for rows where the value in F matches the row number of the cell in G.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use analysis-toolpak Add-on to perform this task:

check out the following URL if you need to know how to load it:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-the-analysis-toolpak-HP001127724.aspx

Regards